# Help, Javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm always fighting with regular expression, some help would be appreciated.

What is the best way to get all parameters (words starting with @) in strings like :

```
statement : "SELECT @Measure on 0, TOPCOUNT(@Hierarchy.levels(1).member) where @Measure"
```

This expression is not working correctly :

```
var paramsNames = mdxStatement.match(/(^|\s|-)+@(\w+)/g);
```

The expected result is : @Measure,@Hierarchy

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
"SELECT @Measure on 0, TOPCOUNT(@Hierarchy.levels(1).member) where @Measure".match(/(@\w+)/g);
```

And remove the last item, if you do not need it.

:)

Answer (score 2):

In this case you will use

```
var match = string.match(/(@\w+)/g);
```

thats it

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
var paramsNames = mdxStatement.match(/(@[a-z]+)/gi);
```

To grab unique params do:

```
var paramsNames = mdxStatement.match(/(@[a-z]+)/gi).unique();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe

```
/@\b.+?\b/g
```

should do what you want

```
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
    var o = {}, i, l = this.length, r = [];
    for(i=0; i<l;i+=1) o[this[i]] = this[i];
    for(i in o) r.push(o[i]);
    return r;
};

var string = "SELECT @Measure on 0, TOPCOUNT(@Hierarchy.levels(1).member) where @Measure";
var pattern = /@\b.+?\b/g;

var params = string.match(pattern).unique();
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/se7Np/1/